# Doctrine remove have to be done twice to work

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a strange behavior on doctrine remove and i don't understand why.
it'an ajax delete  action inside a symfony 5 controller.

If i launch the requete once = nothing appends
If i lauch the requete twice, the delete opperation occur correctly.

Why ?

thanks for your help

```
   /**
 * @Route("/permissions_ajaxDelete", name="permissions_ajaxDelete")
 */   
public function ajaxDelete(Request $request)
{

    $responseArray = array();
    $statusCode = 200;

    //if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

        $id = $request->get('id');
        $permission = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Permissions::class)->find($id);

        //test si la permission existe
        if ($permission != null) {
            $responseArray["successMessage"] = "La permission \"".$permission->getName()."\" d'id ".$permission->getId()." a  été supprimée!";

            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->remove($permission);
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            $permission = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Permissions::class)->find($id);
            if ($permission != null) {
                dd($permission);
                $responseArray["successMessage"] = "bugg";
```

// On a first call, permission is find after the flush/ remove
                }

```
        }else{
            $responseArray["errorMessage"] = "Vous essayez de supprimer une permissions qui n'existe pas.";
            $statusCode = 403;
        }


        return new JsonResponse($responseArray,$statusCode);

    /*}else{
        //Requete non ajax.
        $responseArray["errorMessage"] = "Erreur : Mauvais format de requette (Ajax)";

        return new JsonResponse($responseArray,400);
    }*/


}
```

Comment: did you found the problem?

Comment: I have change a lot of thing so i wasn't be able to find the root cause. Sorry if you have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think after the first 'find' doctrine add entity into unit of work
The second 'find' dont call data base, but only use unit of work to get entity allready loaded !

Using profiler to verify what SQL doctrine call.

Comment: In fact not. if i delete the second find : the first time you call the page : nothing appends (no remove), and on the second call of the page, the remove occurs.